# Generating from openapi to golang using openapi-generator-cli containing oneOf results in broken code

Tags: go, openapi, openapi-generator

Generating golang code using openapi-generator-cli on an `openapi 3.3` spec containing `oneOf` keyword results broken and uncompilable code.
Openapi-generator-cli docker-hub:
`Digest:sha256:829f0b601005c28950ed55c65d853f2caead265730782b2c7c48812bf8135222`

Given this schema:

```
"schemas": {
  "Foo": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "Bar": {
        "oneOf": [
          {"$ref": "#/components/schemas/FooBar"},
          {"$ref": "#/components/schemas/BarFoo"}
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "FooBar": {
    "type": "object",
    "title": "FooBar",
    "properties": {
      "example": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  },
  "BarFoo": {
    "type": "object",
    "title": "BarFoo",
    "properties": {
      "example": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result is:

```
type Foo struct {
    Bar *OneOfFooBarBarFoo `json:"Bar,omitempty"`
}
```

I have read that support for this is limited and should result in interface{} and I would be happy with such a result.
The command i run is:

```
openapi-generator-cli generate \
        -i "/swagger.json" \
        -g go \
        --global-property models,supportingFiles=utils.go,modelDocs=false \
        --additional-properties  \
        --minimal-update \
        -p enumClassPrefix=true \
        --enable-post-process-file \
        --additional-properties packageName="Some Name" \
        -o "/Some_Location"
```

Anyone know of a solution to this? I have tried to find answers, but most of the known issues seems to have been hammered out

Answer (score 0):

The openAPI file as defined leaves a bit of ambiguity. So even if the bindings would compile they would not work correctly. The FooBar and BarFoo schemas need be different as to allow the receiving end to instantiate the right object.

One idea that produces relatively simple code and works is to have a field that carries the type of the object. This is called `discriminator`.

Here is how it fits in your code:

```
schemas:
  Foo:
    type: object
    properties:
      Bar:
        $ref: "#/components/schemas/FooOrBar"
  FooOrBar:
    oneOf:
      - "$ref": "#/components/schemas/FooBar"
      - "$ref": "#/components/schemas/BarFoo"
    discriminator:
      propertyName: className
      mapping:
        FooBar: '#/components/schemas/FooBar'
        BarFoo: '#/components/schemas/BarFoo'
  FooBar:
    type: object
    title: FooBar
    required: [className]
    properties:
      example:
        type: string
      className:
        type: string
  BarFoo:
    type: object
    title: BarFoo
    required: [className]
    properties:
      example:
        type: string
      className:
        type: string
```

Note that I added a new named class to hold the `oneOf` as to have a named container that will be generated. This avoids the problem you observed.

Further to make it a working example I am adding the discriminator.

I lastly added required discriminator property to the two schemas. You can define a "base" schema and include it with `allOf`. The later will produce cleaner and more maintainable code.

In principle, you can forego the "discriminator" and instead define required enumeration fields with a single value in each schema that needs to be selected. I suspect, this will result in less efficient code as the full schema validation will be needed to choose the proper type. With the discriminator approach only one field has to be evaluated.

Again in principle if all your schemas are structurally very different and one cannot validate in place of another discriminator or enum is not necessary. In JSON world the assertion "one cannot validate in place of another" is a very slippery definition. I think it is an outright mistake to use this in JSON schema as upgrades to your schemas may be jeopardized.

I used the following line to emit go code

```
java -jar openapi-generator-cli.jar generate 
  -g go
  -i FooBar.yaml
  -o foo_go
  --additional-properties=useOneOfDiscriminatorLookup=true
  --additional-properties=disallowAdditionalPropertiesIfNotPresent=false
```

Note the `--additional-properties=useOneOfDiscriminatorLookup=true`. This enables logic for the discriminator to be emitted.

The other directive switches the bindings to JSON schema compatible mode i.e. preserve elements not matched by schema. It's a long discussion why you want this. Assume for now there is a reason JSON schema has this assumption.

Note that the same protocol i.e. actual JSON files can be used for Java but in Java you need to use "allOf" construct instead.